# Adding most recent images in directory to web page using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fairly new to javascript/jquery, and I'm trying to add images to a web page based on upload date. I've got images in an images directory, and I want to populate a "portfolio" section with the images, ordered with the most recently added files at the top of the section. How would I do this with js, or, preferably, jquery?

Comment: The Javascript you write for your website will run on the client's machine and not your web server so it has no immediate way to get a list of all the files on your server. To combat this you would need to have something server side that can generate a list of the files (using something like PHP or NodeJS), or you could manually put them in the Javascript code in an array. Because we don't know what you can run on your webserver, it's quite hard to answer this properly.

Comment: You could look into using ajax to call a server-side page that will read/list all images in a selected directory and return them back to the page....

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'll look into learning ajax, and probably also a different method of doing this.